# "Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options." Edit header

Tags: servlets, iframe, http-headers

I am developing an application for a social network. When I try to access it I get an error in my browser:

> Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.

This social network uses Iframe. My question is, how do I change the header to solve this problem?

Considering [Overcoming "Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options), in my servlet I tried command:

```java
httpServletResponse.addHeader("X-FRAME-OPTIONS", "SAMEORIGIN" );
```

Considering http://www.rivercitystudio.com/blog/2011/09/google-maps-embedding-x-frame-options-change/ I've also tried adding in my url the following:

```
&output=embed
```

None of the two alternatives worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's your page that is in the frame, then don't send `X-Frame-Options` at all. The default is to allow embedding.

If it's social network's page that is in the frame, then there's no way to disable it. The whole point of this is prevention of [clickjacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking) via frames.